# File "main.py", line 8 else : ^^^^ SyntaxError: invalid syntax

Tags: python

```
print("lets see if you are eligible for driving in India")
age =int(input("enter your age here !"))

if age >=18:''
  
print("you can drive")

else :

print("you can't drive")
```

ERROR

```
  File "main.py", line 8
    else :
    ^^^^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Comment: Please update your question with the full error traceback.

Comment: You have several basic errors. I'd recommend a structured introduction to the language: https://sopython.com/wiki/What_tutorial_should_I_read%3F

Comment: @quamrana That's it, it just wasn't formatted correctly. BTW, SyntaxErrors normally don't have tracebacks.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please take the [tour]. SO is a Q&A site, but this isn't a question. What do you need help with exactly? To start, do you understand the error message? Check out [ask].

Comment: @wjandrea: Thanks for the reformat. I didn't quite see the `else:` there. That error still doesn't make sense. I would have thought that python would have pointed out other problems before that.

Comment: @quamrana The problem is the `''` in the if-suite, which avoids the indentation error.

Comment: Yes, I see that now. I've just tried it myself. If I didn't think the OP was a newbie, I would think this was a troll.

Answer (score 2):

To fix the syntax error in your code, you need to remove the extra single quotation marks ('') after the if statement. Here's the corrected code:

```py
print("Let's see if you are eligible for driving in India")
age = int(input("Enter your age here: "))

if age >= 18:
    print("You can drive")
else:
    print("You can't drive")
```

In Python, the correct syntax for an if-else statement is to have a colon (:) at the end of the if statement and an indented block of code for each branch of the statement. By removing the extra single quotation marks, you'll have a properly formatted if-else statement that will work as expected.

Comment: MauriceMoss - Your seven answers this month appear likely to have been entirely or partially written by AI (e.g., ChatGPT).  Please be aware that [posting AI-generated content is not allowed here](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/421831). If you used an AI tool to assist with any answer, I would encourage you to delete it. 

We do hope you'll stick around and be a valuable part of our community by posting *your own* quality content. Thanks!

Comment: **Readers should review this answer carefully and critically, as AI-generated information often contains fundamental errors and misinformation.** If you observe quality issues and/or have reason to believe that this answer was generated by AI, please leave feedback accordingly.

Comment: Also keep in mind that questions with typos shouldn't be answered - A comment will suffice along with Flagging the question for closure (as has been done by others in the community here)